# Web Application iOS, Blackberry

Tags: ios, web-applications

I need my application to work with BlackBerry Smartphone and iOS (iPad).

Current I use BlackBerry web works to build and sign my application so it can be used standalone without an internet connection.

I want to do the same for iOS: Sign the application and deploy.

Many people are saying just navigate to the website where your app is and add to bookmark then home screen as described in the Dashcode User Guide ["Testing and Sharing"](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/DebuggingSharing/DebuggingSharing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH16-SW2) and Safari Developer Library article ["Safari Client-Side Storage and Offline Applications Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

But I don't want to host the application on a web server, I just want to build and deploy as this is not public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are asking is, You want to develop an app using web technologies which requires no server for hosting DB.

Also, you don't want the user to user/distribute via bookmark/AddToHomescreen(webclip); you would like to sign the app and distribute via Appstore.

In such case you should look at http://phonegap.com/about which allows you to sign and distribute via app store.

**Update**:

If you want to install it on your device(it is called Adhoc install) you need to have a ios developer account from apple. And you can install using XCode, ios developer program limits no. of devices you can install (100 dev. max).

If you are eligible for Enterprise program, then you can install it on more devices.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response, yes bascily but i dont want to do i via APP Store, i want to manual put in on devices (e.g. Blackberry desktop software to install to my BB) ? Is the possible

Comment: I've updated my response. If it answers your question, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

In iphone and ipad copy all html resource on resource folder and you can all index.html page through webview. Now all html page is now local no need to server side because of it's local path not server path. Now you can build and distribute application on app world.

Let me know any doubt.